# Truncating the Domain of a 1D Graph

Tags: graphics

I have a 1-D graph whose domain is $x \in [0, 15]$. I'd like to domain of the graph to lie between $[0, 5]$ now. I'd ideally want to do it without having to rerun the code. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You can use `Show` to change any options, such as `DataRange` and `PlotRange`. Just copy your graph into `Show`.

Comment: @C.E. `Show[(graph's name), DataRange -> {x, 0, 5}]` doesn't seem to work. I have used `DiscreteListPlot` to plot the graph in the first place.

Comment: `Show[Plot[],PlotRange->{{0,5},{y-,y+}}]`

Comment: @JunaidAftab `DiscretePlot` doesn't have the `DataRange` option. I was just making the point that you can change any options that you want to change with `Show`.

Answer (score 2):

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x] + Sin[.5 x], {x, 0, 15}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

```
(* act like an operator *)
redomain[range_][plot_] :=
 plot /. HoldPattern[PlotRange -> {_, y_}] :> PlotRange -> {range, y}

plot // redomain[{0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Are there cases where you would recommend this approach over `Show`?

Comment: @C.E. You're right, `Show` is better for this example, though it must be something like `Show[plot, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, Automatic}]` to get the y-range right.